# will downgrading mysql 5.5 to mysql 5.0 or 5.1 cause data loss?

Tags: mysql

For some reasons I have to downgrade MySQL so:

Will downgrading MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.0 or 5.1 cause data loss?

Comment: Why don't you make a backup before, then downgrade the databse and if something got lost you have your backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to export your data.

Remove mysql 5.5 server software and install desired version.

Then use mysql client to import.

You can follow **[official downgrade guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/downgrading-to-previous-series.html)**

Based on this document, only change is default storage engine has changed to InnodDB, so no problem should occures.

[Upgrade guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) can explain what has changed from 5.1 to 5.5.

Never ever copy data files directly !!!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that its better to have a backup of your data, as you never know when you can have a data loss.

From mysql documentation.

> The following items form a checklist of things you should do whenever
>   you perform a downgrade:
>
> Read the upgrading section for the release series from which you are 
>   downgrading to be sure that it does not have any features you
>   really need. See Section 2.19.1, “Upgrading MySQL”.
>
> If there is a downgrading section for that version, you should read
>   that as well.
>
> To see which new features were added between the version to which 
>   you are downgrading and your current version, see the change logs >
>   (Appendix D, MySQL Change History).
>
> Check Section 2.19.3, “Checking Whether Tables or Indexes Must Be Rebuilt”, 
>   to see whether changes to table formats or to character sets
>   or collations were made between your current version of MySQL and the
>   version to which you are downgrading. If so and these changes result
>   in an incompatibility between MySQL versions, you will need to
>   downgrade the affected tables using the instructions in Section
>   2.19.4, “Rebuilding or Repairing Tables or Indexes”.

For details [check here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/downgrading.html)